# How to report progress from TableAdapter.Update

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net, progress, tableadapter

I am writing some data to my Database using `TableAdpater.Update` and the operation can take up to one minute to complete.

Is there some way to report the progress of this to the user because they think it has stopped responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to implement a Custom TableAdapter class and override `'Update'` ( Sorry for the VB.NET - its just what I had open )

```
Public Class CustomDataAdapter : Inherits DataAdapter
     Public Overrides Function Update(dataSet As System.Data.DataSet) As Integer
            For Each row In dataSet.Tables(x).Rows
                ' Insert/Update into table
                ' Callback to a progressbar updater
            Next
        End Function
End Class
```

Comment: No need to apologize... +1 for VB.Net.